# How to replace strings with values in an array using gulp replace

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace, gulp, gulp-replace

I have an XML file where I need to replace attribute values with the values from an array using GulpJS.

JavaScript code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'); 
var replace = require('gulp-replace'); 
gulp.task('default', function() {   
    //array is dynamic
    var users = ["existing_value1", "existing_value2", "existing_value3"];  
    var num = users.length();
    for (i=0;i<num;i++) {
        gulp.src(['idmap/*.xml'])
            .pipe(replace(users[i], 'SYSTEM'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
    } 
});
```

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><IDMAP><RECORD>
<TOKEN data = "414"/><NAME data="existing_value1"/></RECORD>
<RECORD><TOKEN data = "420"/><NAME data="existing_value2"/></RECORD>   
<RECORD><TOKEN data = "361"/><NAME data="existing_value3"/></RECORD> 
</IDMAP>
```

With this code, I'm able to replace the string in XML with the last item in array. How to replace all the items with the ones in array and then do the build?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time your **for** loop run it overwrite the **dest** file. That's why you have replaced only the last item in your *array*.

**gulp-replace** only support `String` or `RegExp` as a *search* parameter. Therefore I would suggest that you write your own plugin. It would be something like this:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rs = require('replacestream');
var through = require('through2');

gulp.task('default', function() {   
  var users = ["existing_value1", "existing_value2", "existing_value3"];
  gulp.src(['idmap/*.xml'])
    .pipe(replaceArray(users, 'SYSTEM'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'))
});

/**
 * This is your plugin inspired in gulp-replace
 *
 * @method replaceArray
 * @param  {Array} searchArray
 * @param  {String} replacement
 */
function replaceArray(searchArray, replacement) {
  return through.obj(function(file, encoding, callback) {
    if (file.isStream()) {
      file.contents = searchArray.reduce(function (contents, search) {
        return contents.pipe(rs(search, replacement));
      }, file.contents);
      return callback(null, file);
    }
    if (file.isBuffer()) {
      var result = searchArray.reduce(function (contents, array) {
        return contents
          .split(search)
          .join(replacement);
      }, String(file.contents));
      file.contents = new Buffer(result);
      return callback(null, file);
    }
    callback(null, file);
  });
}
```

Comment: @king, I am not sure how `Array.prototype.replace` will behave with `Streams`. Try it out and let me know.

Comment: thank you once again! the following worked,

`code`

function replaceArray(searchArray, replacement) {
    return through.obj(function(file, encoding, callback) {
        if (file.isBuffer()) {
            var result = searchArray.reduce(function(contents, searchArray) {
                return contents.split(searchArray).join(replacement);
            }, String(file.contents));
            file.contents = new Buffer(result);
            return callback(null, file);
        }
        callback(null, file);
    });
} 

`code`

Comment: @king, if it worked for you, Would you mind to upvote and accept the answer? :)

Comment: accepted it as answer, tried upvoting but giving notification stating I have not enough reputation to do so..!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using regex. If you can it would be better if you could write a pattern that would match all the attributes you want. For example, this would work on your example:

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.src(['idmap/*.xml'])
        .pipe(replace(/existing_value\d+/g, 'SYSTEM'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
});
```

But if your attributes are more complicated than that you can generate a dynamic expression from your `users` array:

```
gulp.task('default', function() {

    var users = ['existing_value1', 'existing_value2', 'existing_value3'];
    var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + users.join('\\b|\\b') + '\\b', 'g');

    gulp.src(['idmap/*.xml'])
        .pipe(replace(regex, 'SYSTEM'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));

});
```

Comment: Thank you @MadScone for your help! I couldn't go with regex as the attributes are bit complicated as you rightly mentioned.